# PHP Push notification service, feedback is empty,how can i to do

Tags: php, ios, user-feedback

The push works just fine, the problem is that the feedback is empty. I need to delete the tokens that have expired or have an invalid status.This is what I write test code，this a problem?]

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(); 
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem'); 
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196', $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx); 
if (!$fp) { 
  return; 
} 
while ($devcon = fread($fp,38)) { 
  $arr = unpack("H*", $devcon); 
  $rawhex = trim(implode("", $arr)); 
  $feedbackTime = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 0, 8)); 
  $feedbackDate = date('Y-m-d H:i', $feedbackTime); 
  $feedbackLen = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 8, 4)); 
  $feedbackDeviceToken = substr($rawhex, 12, 64); 
} 
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Can you show us your codes, request (contents you wrote in SSH tunnel) and response ?

Comment: $ctx = stream_context_create();  
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196', $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);  
if (!$fp) {   
 return;  
}       
while ($devcon = fread($fp,38))  
{  
$arr = unpack("H*", $devcon);  
$rawhex = trim(implode("", $arr));  
$feedbackTime = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 0, 8));  
$feedbackDate = date('Y-m-d H:i', $feedbackTime);  
$feedbackLen = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 8, 4));  
$feedbackDeviceToken = substr($rawhex, 12, 64);   
}  
fclose($fp);

Answer (score 2):

Feedback services don't always return data. You will get data only if there is need to report failed deliveries.

See the [documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3).

Not sure if this is true but I have noticed feedback services don't work with the sandbox environment (at least I haven't received a response any time I checked with sandbox)